# Passing a dynamically generated form to a controller

Tags: javascript, forms, grails

This is my JavaScript function to generate checkboxes at run time based on an XML file when a user clicks on a create button:

```
function createform(){
       var xml = '<root><note ><to>x1</to><from><firstname>x2</firstname><lastname>x3</lastname></from><heading>x4</heading></note><note><to>x5</to><from><firstname>x6</firstname><lastname>x7</lastname></from><heading>x8</heading></note></root>';
       var node = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml, "text/xml").documentElement;
       var nodes = node.querySelectorAll("*");
       for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
          var label = document.createElement('label');
          var br = document.createElement('br');

          var alabel = document.getElementById('div');
          var last = alabel[alabel.length - 1];
          label.htmlFor = "lbl"+i;
          label.appendChild(Createcheckbox(nodes[i].tagName));

          label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(nodes[i].tagName));
          label.appendChild(br);

          document.getElementById('div').appendChild(label);
       }
    }

    function Createcheckbox(chkboxid) {
       var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
       checkbox.type = "checkbox";
       checkbox.id = chkboxid;
       checkbox.value = chkboxid; 
       checkbox.checked = false;
       return checkbox;
    }
```

Also on my gsp page, I have this HTML script.

```
<body>
<g:form name="myForm" controller="dynamicform" action="index">
<input type="button" id="btncreate" value="Create" onclick="createform()"/>
<g:submitButton name="submit" value="Submit" />
<Div id='div'>
</div>
</g:form>
</body>
```

Since the elements in this form are unknown until the user clicks the "create" button, I'm not sure what is the best way to handle this form.

I need to pass the values of the elements to a controller to render them in a view (I'll need to use these values later to retrieve some data from my database).

I tried different ways to view these elements after submission, such as:

```
for (name in params.list('name')) {
    println name
}
```

and

```
params.name.each{i->System.out.println(i);}
```

It seems that my params are not passed to the controller. Is that because my form elements generated using regular HTML instead of Grails forms `<g: checkbox ... >`, so the DOM elements can't be passed to the controller? If yes, is there a way to re-write my createform() function using Grails form?

I'm trying to follow best practices while learning Grails so I'd appreciate any suggestion or advice about that.

Comment: `params.list('name')` and `params.name` both look for parameters named "name" - to see all of your parameter names and values use `println params` at the beginning of the controller method.

Comment: what is the output if you `println params` in controller? Within a form, any input/select/checkbox with `name` attribute will be passed to controller. In your JS function `createform()` doesn't seem to have codes for adding `name` attribute, can you post the `Createcheckbox` too? did you check in browser console whats passing with the http request? Did you inspect you page if the generated html codes are in right place (in form)?

Comment: **regular HTML** works completely fine inside GSP pages. The main difference between a HTML and a GSP file is, in gsp file you can put in some groovy/java codes, and it renders corresponding HTML codes for you.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith I tried that but I think the parameters are not passed to the controller properly. I got null. I guess it has something to do with the way I'm creating the form.

Comment: @devbd the output is null. I realized that I deleted 'name' attribute and used 'id' instead but still getting null. I updated the post with my function.

Comment: please give me an example "xml" file you are trying to parse. I may try to run the codes you have.

Comment: @devbd I updated the first function with an xml variable I'm using to test everything. I'm sure everything works fine except for the passing step. The controller doesn't receive any params, and it seems the problem is due the way I'm generating this form.

Comment: sorry for the late response. thanks for the updates. please check the answer, don't forget to **accept + upvote**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple fix -

```
function Createcheckbox(chkboxid) {
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.id = chkboxid;
    checkbox.value = chkboxid;
    checkbox.checked = false;
    checkbox.name = chkboxid; // <-- the fix!!!
    return checkbox;
}
```

In controller: `println params`

> [submit:Submit, note:note, to:to, lastname:lastname, heading:heading,
>   controller:dynamicform, action:index]

[image]

**Comment** : In HTML form submit, any input with a `name` attribute will be submitted. Without `name` attr no form data will be passed to server.

**Suggestion** : Place your JS function `Createcheckbox(chkboxid)` before `createform()`

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't expect the fix to be that simple! 
Is it possible to iterate over the params when each element has a different name? or do I need to use one name for all checkboxes in that case?

Comment: sure, you can iterate over the params. In case, with same name for multiple checkboxes, you will get the values as `List` . Please check more, if you find complexity, you may post new question with your usecase.

Comment: sorry.. I can't upvote. I still don't have 15 reputation.